# Force download video from youtube dl from browser

Tags: node.js, youtube-dl

I use a library called `youtube dl` that fetch a download link for youtube video and i get the url correct

and here is an example of it

```
https://r2---sn-uxaxjvhxbt2u-5at6.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?expire=1577139299&ei=A-gAXuKOOcajVeuhiNAG&ip=156.210.188.56&id=o-AIMsVKrgAzchflwvC8RghEdaFx_qidHvNxF4CrsjzjKs&itag=22&source=youtube&requiressl=yes&mm=31%2C29&mn=sn-uxaxjvhxbt2u-5at6%2Csn-5hne6nsy&ms=au%2Crdu&mv=m&mvi=1&pl=18&initcwndbps=196250&mime=video%2Fmp4&ratebypass=yes&dur=809.749&lmt=1572659309400505&mt=1577117629&fvip=2&fexp=23842630&c=WEB&txp=5532432&sparams=expire%2Cei%2Cip%2Cid%2Citag%2Csource%2Crequiressl%2Cmime%2Cratebypass%2Cdur%2Clmt&sig=ALgxI2wwRgIhAMrLlARE6aG-ooI1Qe9qpxmniWpMNDG_lE3egvIrftliAiEAg7LELBlJ1gs5d-7dBkSM4J1hw7flEYDhwCn9ez19YrM%3D&lsparams=mm%2Cmn%2Cms%2Cmv%2Cmvi%2Cpl%2Cinitcwndbps&lsig=AHylml4wRQIhAKalOjpgvfKSwt5mRFqKJZgGA6vRKhueoT2mxgBKEBbqAiB1fN858sxAWZn422GzqdZw4yb4YOBC9tDvwOLukPMwXA%3D%3D
```

but the problem is i try to make an anchor tag or something like this to download it i tried

```
<a download href="youtube-dl-url">download</a>
```

but it still `redirect` me to the video not download it

Comment: Can you link the library? `youtube-dl` is a specific library, not the process of downloading from YouTube!

Comment: https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl

Comment: OK, so you want to use `youtube-dl` with Node.js? Did you already write code? Or do you want to use the command line tool?

Comment: i write code and it fetch to me the video url like the example im question but i need to make button to force download it not to redirect to the video

Comment: So you want to link the "video url"?

Comment: yes, and it try to add the line in `a` tag `<a download href="download-link-here">downalod</a>` but it redirect me

Comment: I've just checked your example link. Most probably some requirements have to be met to be able to open such a link. That's why `youtube-dl` was written...